# Unable to start the Genymotion virtual device

Tags: virtualbox

I installed Genymotion and VirtualBox successfully and download 1 of the virtual machines. but when I run the Genymotion, receive this error!

[image]

Comment: From the Genymotion FAQ: Q: When you start a virtual device, you get an error about OpenGL initialization. A:
This is probably due to an outdated video driver, or a very old video chipset.
Try to update your graphic card driver using the latest version provided by your manufacturer (available on their website).

Comment: @onik I have an updated **GFORCE 9400** GT on my computer! Is that enough?!

Comment: That video card has support for OpenGL 2.1, which was released back in 2006. Judging by the error message, it's not enough for Genymotion, or there's a driver conflict. I'd recommend moving this to SuperUser, since it's not an Android question, but a driver issue.